# build app package with Multilingual App Toolkit

Tags: msbuild, multilingual

There is a strange thing, when I build the app package in IDE using Create App Packages wizard, the multilingual is correct.

But if i build it with msbuild.exe in command line, like:

```
msbuild.exe my.sln /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86;Outdir=myoutput /flp:LogFile=my.log
```

the result app package is wrong. It has no the multilingual resource, just the default English.

what's the different in IDE wizard and msbuild.exe? Is my command line wrong?

the log is:

```
    Target "AfterBuild" in project "myproject.csproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
Using "MultilingualBuild" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Multilingual App Toolkit\v1.0\Microsoft.Multilingual.Build.dll".
Task "MultilingualBuild"
  Multilingual App Toolkit build started.
  Update build config xml started.
  Preprocessing XLIFF file: 'MultilingualResources\Chinese (Simplified).xlf'
  Preprocessing XLIFF file: 'MultilingualResources\Chinese (Traditional).xlf'
  Preprocessing XLIFF file: 'MultilingualResources\Italian (Italy).xlf'
  Preprocessing XLIFF file: 'MultilingualResources\Japanese (Japan).xlf'
  Preprocessing XLIFF file: 'MultilingualResources\Russian (Russia).xlf'
  Update build config xml completed.
  Generate latest XLIFF build task started.
  A translation unit with null or empty content was detected and ignored while generating the XLIFF file.
  A translation unit with null or empty content was detected and ignored while generating the XLIFF file.
  A translation unit with null or empty content was detected and ignored while generating the XLIFF file.
  A translation unit with null or empty content was detected and ignored while generating the XLIFF file.
  Latest XLIFF file generated: 'obj\x86\Release\MultilingualAppToolkitLatest.xlf'
  Generate latest XLIFF build task completed.
  Update XLIFF build started.
  TargetLang  ID: zh-Hans
  TargetLang XLiff: MultilingualResources\Chinese (Simplified).xlf
  XLIFF file updated: 'MultilingualResources\Chinese (Simplified).xlf'
  TargetLang  ID: zh-Hant
  TargetLang XLiff: MultilingualResources\Chinese (Traditional).xlf
  XLIFF file updated: 'MultilingualResources\Chinese (Traditional).xlf'
  TargetLang  ID: it-IT
  TargetLang XLiff: MultilingualResources\Italian (Italy).xlf
  XLIFF file updated: 'MultilingualResources\Italian (Italy).xlf'
  TargetLang  ID: ja-JP
  TargetLang XLiff: MultilingualResources\Japanese (Japan).xlf
  XLIFF file updated: 'MultilingualResources\Japanese (Japan).xlf'
  TargetLang  ID: ru-RU
  TargetLang XLiff: MultilingualResources\Russian (Russia).xlf
  XLIFF file updated: 'MultilingualResources\Russian (Russia).xlf'
  Update XLIFF build completed.
  Generate priInfo build started.
  Adding language 'zh-Hans' from 'MultilingualResources\Chinese (Simplified).xlf'
  Adding language 'zh-Hant' from 'MultilingualResources\Chinese (Traditional).xlf'
  Adding language 'it-IT' from 'MultilingualResources\Italian (Italy).xlf'
  Adding language 'ja-JP' from 'MultilingualResources\Japanese (Japan).xlf'
  Adding language 'ru-RU' from 'MultilingualResources\Russian (Russia).xlf'
  Generate priInfo build completed.
  Merge of Loc PRI file started.
  Copy App PRI file started.
  Copy App PRI file completed.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\Makepri.exe resourcepack /o /pr "C:\hudsonprojects\myproject\sourcecode\myproject\myproject" /cf "obj\x86\Release\MultilingualAppToolkit.cfg.xml" /if "obj\x86\Release\MultilingualAppToolkit.pri" /of "../../../output/myproject/resources.pri"
  Update Manifest File Started.
  Update Manifest File added language id: 'zh-Hans'
  Update Manifest File added language id: 'zh-Hant'
  Update Manifest File added language id: 'it-IT'
  Update Manifest File added language id: 'ja-JP'
  Update Manifest File added language id: 'ru-RU'
  Update Manifest File is saving the manifest changes.
  Update Manifest File Completed.
  Merge of Loc PRI file completed.
  Multilingual App Toolkit build completed successfully.
Done executing task "MultilingualBuild".
Done building target "AfterBuild" in project "myproject.csproj".
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using t:/publish instead:

```
msbuild.exe my.sln /t:publish /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86;Outdir=myoutput /flp:LogFile=my.log
```

See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7522e6a3-1a74-42df-9414-bb93d745a0ca/why-msbuild-cannot-create-apppackage-

Also, while I did not see it in the output log, make sure that Pseudo is excluded before creating a package to publish.  Pseudo is create for localization testing, it will not pass store certification.

Comment: Just one additional comment, as I found this out the hard way. Not only will Pseudo localization not pass store certification, it will prevent all languages other than the default from entering `resources.pri`, which appears to be the phenomenon the OP is seeing.

Answer (score 0):

A little hard to say without more information, it could be `Platform` should be `AnyCPU` rather than `x86`, it just depends on how your solution is configured.

Have you tried bumping up the MSBuild output verbosity to analyse in more detail?

> Visual Studio: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > ...
>
> Command Line: /verbosity:detailed

If you can't see the discrepancy after trying that, perhaps update your question with more  detailed log output.

Comment: Thanks. I try the other platform configure and still wrong. And the log is attached. I compared the output of IDE wizard and the msbuild, found the pri file is different, I guess msbuild has something wrong when it create the pri file.

Comment: Visual Studio calls MSBuild under the covers, so you should be able to track it down.